# What is the relation or difference between adding javax-servlet dependency in pom.xml and setting Dynamic web module in project facets?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have read eclipse documentation on project facets as:

> Facets define characteristics and requirements for Java EE projects and are used as part of the runtime configuration.When you add a facet to a project, that project is configured to perform a certain task, fulfill certain requirements, or have certain characteristics.

And about maven dependencies as:
**Maven is a powerful project management tool that is based on POM (project object model). It is used for projects build, dependency and documentation.**

My question is when I select Dynamic web module in eclipse as project facets then it adds support for Java servlet API, for generation of Web Page Content then why do I need to add **javax.servlet-api** dependency in pom.xml in eclipse?

I have read different answers on how to enable Dynamic web module in project facets but none could solve my query. 
Are these two things inter related or entirely different?
If anyone can please explain this to me in simple words rather than giving any link to read or marking question as duplicate then it would be a great help. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a maven project, not only servlet if later you need any external utility modules like Jackson or any other you just need to add the specific entry in pom.xml and maven resolves it for you if its available in maven repository. There are lot other advantages with Maven.

But for Dynamic Web Project you need to configure the additional libraries for the external jars whenever you need something that jdk does not provide you.

This is just a naive difference which may help you in understanding the basic difference.

And to answer your question whether they are related or not: They are no where related.

Comment: I know that using maven we can add various dependency in our project, but I want to know do these both things do same work or not?

Comment: If by "work" you mean dependency management yes they serve the same purpose, but you can achieve in two different ways, and maven is lot more convenient.

Comment: Means if I dont add servlet-api dependency in pom then too maven project will be deployed on tomcat?

Comment: No you need to add the dependency in pom.xml. Even in Dynamic web project the servlet jars are included in the class path. If you go to configure build path option you can see the external servlet jar.

Comment: Yes I have to add dependency for it in pom.xml , that is what I am asking that what is the difference between the working of these two processes. What does dynamic web module do and what does maven do independently?

Comment: In that case if you don't add any dependency both for dynamic web project and maven only the jdk default libraries will be available for use. It's the same.

Comment: Can you please accept the answer if it suffices your query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171334/discussion-between-shepherd-and-adya).